# Make variable common to all subclasses

Tags: python

I want a class `temp` with a variable `a`, and its two subclasses `c1` and `c2`. If `a` is changed in `c1`, it should also be reflected in `c2` and vice-versa. For this, I tried:

```
class temp(ABC):

    a=1

    def f(self):
        pass

class c1(temp):

    def f(self):
        print(self.a)

class c2(temp):

    def f(self):
        print(self.a)

o1=c1()
o2=c2()
o1.f()
o2.f()
o1.a+=1
o1.f()
o2.f()
```

It gives me output:

```
1
1
2
1
```

whereas I want it to be

```
1
1
2
2
```

I also tried `super.a` instead of `self.a`, but it gives me an error. How can I achieve the desired target? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than incrementing `o1.a`, you need to increment the static variable itself.

Ie `temp.a += 1`

```
class temp():
    a=1
    def f(self):
        pass

class c1(temp):
    def f(self):
        print(self.a)

class c2(temp):
    def f(self):
        print(self.a)

o1=c1()
o2=c2()
o1.f()
o2.f()
temp.a+=1
o1.f()
o2.f()

>>> 1
    1
    2
    2
```

Comment: He wants to change o1 and o2, and not temp, from the OP `If a is changed in c1, it should also be reflected in c2 and vice-versa.`, but you are updating the base class

Comment: It may sound stupid, but I don't know why I didn't think of that

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh even if I change something in `c1`, I can instead change it in `temp`, because `c1` is it's subclass

Comment: sure, then perhaps you would want to reword your question!